# Qt (Python): Change the appearance of a dragged QWidget

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, pyside, pyside6

I currently have a `QTreeView` with different `QStandardItem`s in its model in a Python application (usign PySide6). I'd like to let the items to be draggable (easily done setting a couple of flags), but once dragged, I'd like the dragged item (not the original `QStandardItem`) to appear as a completely different custom `QWidget`; if not possible, I'd like at least to let the dragged item appear as a generic png placeholder.

May you please help me?

Thanks :)

Comment: `QSimpleItem`? Don't you mean `QStandardItem`?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: The items themselves aren't ever dragged, only pixmaps of them. You need to reimplement [startDrag](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#_ZN17QAbstractItemView9startDragE6QFlagsIN2Qt10DropActionEE) and set a custom pixmap on the [drag object](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdrag.html#setPixmap).

Comment: Thanks for the hint @ekhumoro! I was misdirected because I thought I'd overwrite the QStandardItem (extended) class, but that's not actually a QWidget and thus has no startDrag method to reimplement!

Comment: The drag operation is performed by the view, not the dragged items.

Comment: I'm a bit lost as to what you actually want to do.  Do you want to change the drag cursor image as suggested by @ekhumoro or do you want to change the appearance of the drag source model index as seen in the `QTreeView`?  Or something else?  Perhaps you could provide an image demonstrating what you are trying to achieve.